# Is there something like Snoop (WPF) or FireBug (ASP.NET) for Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I want to point with the mouse on an area in my application and know the name of the UserControl.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hawkeye (seems moved to [github](https://github.com/odalet/Hawkeye2)) can do that and more. You can see all the properties, fields, events and methods of a control. You can also edit the properties during runtime.

Comment: +1 Great utility. Very powerful. wfSpy is a little easier to use though (see my answer).

Answer (score 9):

I recommend [WinSpy++](http://www.catch22.net/software/winspy) because its much easier to get hold of then the original Spy++ which comes as part of the Windows SDK.

Just like Spy++ this only works at the Win32 level, of which WinForms is a thin/medium wrapper.

Comment: Could you use this to discover where an icon is being loaded from? I'm trying to find the assembly some of Visual Studio 2013's context menu icons are stored in.

Answer (score 5):

**My favorite (for ease of use) is our modified wfSpy utility.**

It is available at my blog:
http://www.cplotts.com/2009/10/28/an-ode-to-wfspy/

The original utility is from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/wfspy.aspx) ... but that version doesn't have the ability to drag the mouse on top of a control in your application.

Hawkeye (already mentioned above) is a favorite of mine as well ... more powerful than wfSpy ... but definitely harder to use. wfSpy is great for quick and simple spying (and of course editing of properties on the fly).

Answer (score 1):

I havn't tried it, but there is a tool called [ManagedSpy](https://web.archive.org/web/20130512001443/http://geekswithblogs.net/Blake/archive/2009/02/03/developer-toolkit-ndash-managed-spy.aspx) ([Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2006/april/using-net-deliver-the-power-of-spy-to-windows-forms)) that might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Spy++ allow you to see Window settings and messages, but that works at native (Win32) level, and will not show .NET information.