# Why is this Win Form not displaying properly?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-3.5

I've created a SSIS custom control flow component written in .Net 3.5 C#, which is installed through a MSI file.  The installation works absolutely fine on a dev Windows XP Machine, a dev Windows 7 machine, and a dev Windows 8 machine.
I've had to do a few updates to the application which weren't interface related and prior to the changes I made the form displayed absolutely fine.  I've just handed the setup program over to a user with a Windows 7 machine and when I open one of the forms its not loading properly.  Its not populating any of the comboboxes and is displaying controls which should be otherwise hidden.  I can't work out why though.  I've run Windows updates on the user machines, its completely up to date.  I've uninstalled, and reinstalled, restarted the machine multiple times.  I've done some googling and can't work out why its not working.  Has anyone ever had something like this before if so how did you resolve it.

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the overlaps on your labels and input controls? You might want to highlight that on the images.

Comment: Can you share that what is logic for showing/hiding the hidden controls ? and What you have tried in logic to check ?

Comment: If this was WPF I would have used [Snoop](http://www.snoopwpf.codeplex.com)

Comment: I think you have dependency issues unrelated to .NET.  Does the other client have the same database client software, do you use fixed path for user settings instead of the special folders that move with each version of Windows?

Comment: As this is WinForms try checking with [WinSpy++](http://www.catch22.net/software/winspy) I just got to know from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2260717/468718) ;)

Comment: Are you custom controls or application throwing an error, but have you have caught and ignored it?

Comment: @zeecat have you solved your problem ?

Comment: @Schwarzie2478 this was the issue.  In the setup project I had told it to copy the project output.  It wasn't picking up some of the dependency dll's.  I've manually added them to the setup solution.  If you put this as an answer I'll acknowledge it.  Unfortunately I can't use WinSpy++ or any other application unless its on my own machine.  I can't install any 3rd party applications as it has to stay a UAT\Dev environment but I'll remember to use this on my own machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have dependency issues unrelated to .NET. Does the other client have the same database client software, do you use fixed path for user settings instead of the special folders that move with each version of Windows?