# How to get all the controls on a .Net Application dynamically?

Tags: c#, winforms, eventhandler

I have been researching from the past couple days on how to write a method in C# that can dynamically get all the controls while clicked on a .Net Application. Most of the examples out there are on buttons that you specify for example

```
ctl.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseClick);
```

In the above example we are specifying `Form1_MouseClick`.

What I am looking for is Dynamically get all the controls and its properties from any .Net Application you Click. TO give an example **IF I have 2 .Net Apps one with 3 combo boxes and another app with 3 buttons, when I click on the first one it should tell me there are 3 combo boxes and show its properties and while I click on second it should tell me that there are 3 buttons and their properties.** Something like an object Spy for .Net purely in C#

My problem is I do not know where to start and I would really appreciate if someone can just point me in the right direction.

Comment: [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [WinForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd30h2yb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: @dbc, sounds like winforms to me (Form1_MouseClick). Yes, clicks can be in WPF as well, but we usually don't call the windows forms.

Comment: I have no idea, but its highly non-trivial. Snoop is an open source project that does it for WPF apps. Apps that do it for windows forms can be found at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260691/is-there-something-like-snoop-wpf-or-firebug-asp-net-for-windows-forms but I don't know if any are open source. I would look at the code of one to guide you.

Comment: If your problem is you don't know where to start, StackOverflow is not the place to ask. We want specific questions - this one is too broad.

Comment: Maybe try google about the workings of Spy. Then rebuild it using pinvoke in C#. I do think this is the easiest way of going about (if target apps are WinForms)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.reflection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
foreach (var control in <YourForm>.Controls)
        {
            var props = control.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (var propertyInfo in props.Where(p=>p.PropertyType == typeof(string)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} - Value: {1}", propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.GetValue(control, null));
            }
        }
```

This is only an example of how you could achieve your goals.

Cheers,
Martin

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to do this on *other* windows.

Comment: Hm, then i missunderstood his question. He wrote that he has a .net app with 3 combos and when he hit on that .net app he get all the properties within this app.

Comment: And then he wants to click *another* window and get its controls, basically his own Spy++ or Snoop tool.

Comment: In that case you are right and my answer is crap :) Sorry for that.

Comment: @MartinE if you get down votes delete this to fix your rep ;)